# Load-Balancing in Apache2.4 using mod_jk

Tags: html, apache, session, mod-jk, apache2.4

- Recently we have developed application with JAVA,HTML5,JQUERY,JBOSS-7.1.1,Apache2.4
- my configuration details between Apache2.4 to JBoss is :
  mod_jk.so & mod-jk.conf & workers.properties

------------------- configurations----------------------------------------------

**mod-jk.conf**

```
  LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so

  JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties

  JkShmFile logs/mod_jk.shm

  JkLogFile logs/mod_jk.log

  JkLogLevel info

  #JkMount /TestForApache2/ loadbalancer

  JkMount /Application/* loadbalancer
```

**workers.properties**

```
worker.list=loadbalancer

   worker.jboss.host=192.168.1.105

   worker.jboss.port=8009

   worker.jboss.type=ajp13

   worker.jboss.cachesize=100

   worker.jboss.lbfactor=1

   worker.loadbalancer.type=lb

   worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=jboss
```

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
  DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/htdocs/html5"

  ServerName localhost

  ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"

  CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common

  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

  JkMount /Application/* loadbalancer
```

- we are facing the issue is :

  when Multiple Users access my application from **application.mysite.com** then its going to hanging login page,if single user the its working fine.
- i am new in this Apache2.4 i have tried with multiple changes like: [i followed artical](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossclustering/cluster_guide/5.1/html/clustering-http.html)

  when i restart the Apache2.4 from services then its working fine,
- and we are using session ids in jboss 
  i.e. when logged in user then creating session send to user browser like: **application.mysite.com/main/header.html?sessionId=oMzxRpLUkF8FX0r7NkMlWqOV.jboss**
- please can any once help me for changes in configuration changes,
- thanks in advance & please save my days.